# Vi: "$s/$/done/" is "not an editor command"?

Tags: vim, vi

I am writing an infinite loop in bash:

```
while :
do
   (whatever)
done
```

However, when I try to insert the "done" line in this way

```
vi -c "$s/$/\rdone\r/g" -c "w!" -c "q!"
```

What I get is that "$s/$/\rdone\r/g" is not an editor command. However, this works fine while I'm on gvim.

Does anybody has any idea why this is happening? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What exactly does vim tell you is not an editor command?

Comment: Vim seems like an unusual choice for this task. Why not sed or awk?

Answer (score 3):

Just replace double quotes by single ones:

```
vim yourfile -c '$s/$/\rdone\r' -c 'wq!'
```

Double quotes are parsed by bash first, and it's especially a problem with the `$` signs.

Answer (score 0):

`vi` is an ancient tool. I don't have a copy of it, so I can't test your command in vi, but your command works fine for me if I use vim. Try doing this instead:

```
vim file -c "$s/$/\rdone\r/g" -c "w!" -c "q!"
```

Also, as a side note, the `w` and `q` commands can be combined for

```
vim file -c "$s/$/\rdone\r/g" -c "wq!"
```

and the globals flag (`/g`) is unneeded since `$` can only match once on the line.

```
vim file -c "$s/$/\rdone\r" -c "wq!"
```

That should be a little bit more efficient.

Comment: @JoshLee Ah, I see the problem now. This worked fine for me because I tried it on windows, not in bash. I didn't realize bash had problems with double quotes.